# How do I give score (0/1) to CSV rows

Tags: python, csv

My csv file row column data looks like this -

```
a a a a a
b b b b b
c c c c c
d d d d d
a b c d e
a d b c c
```

When I have patterns like row 1-5, I want to return value 0
When I have row like 6 or random alphabets (not like row 1-5), I want to return value 1.

How do I do it using python?It must be done by using csv file

Comment: Please do not use images -- use actual text. Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can read your csv file to pandas dataframe using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(header=None)
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  a  a  a  a  a
1  b  b  b  b  b
2  c  c  c  c  c
3  d  d  d  d  d
4  a  b  c  d  e
5  a  d  b  c  c
```

Then, use `nunique` to count the number of unique values per row, if 1 or 5 (the max), then it is valid, else not. Use `between` for that.

```
df.nunique(1).between(2, len(df.columns)-1).astype(int)
```

output:

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: But my question was if its like row 1-5 then it should return 0. Otherwise 1

Comment: also for row 4 it should return same as row 1-3

Comment: @tomtom check the update. I'm sure you could have figured it out by yourself ;)